# How to add a profile tab via views

Tags: views, 8

On the profile page that is `/user/1` for e.g how to add tab MY ADS to be `/user/1/myads`?

Answer (score 1):

Create a view page and add a menu item entry: "Default menu tab" to "Menu tab" and select "User Menu" in dropdown in your view.

Answer (score 0):

- Create a view page
- Change the path to: **user/%user/myads**
- Change menu to '**Menu tab**' and make sure the parent is '**-- My account**'